# Paste Special error 1004 PasteSpecial method of Range class failed

Tags: vba, excel

I have looked thoroughly at the current answers for this problem and none of them have fixed mine.

The operation is simply copying a selection of a sheet and copying to a new book called budget.

Again I have tried multiple different ways of doing the same thing and none of them seem to change this error. The select method works,it only breaks when I try to paste.

Code:

```
Range("B3").Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select
Selection.Copy

Dim wk As Workbook
Set wk = Workbooks.Add

wk.SaveAs FileName:=ThisWorkbook.path & "\" & "Budget.xlsx"
wk.Activate
wk.Unprotect
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Select
Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Thanks,

Comment: try the Record Macro button and see how the copy-paste code is different than yours. It's a very finicky syntax sometimes.

Comment: Keep in mind that `ThisWorkbook` will not have a path if it's a new Workbook and that will cause the code to fail too. You may want to include a check to make sure it has a path.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the code below (explanation inside the code as comments):

```
Dim wk As Workbook
Set wk = Workbooks.Add

wk.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Budget.xlsx"
wk.Activate
wk.Unprotect

' have the Copy>>Paste section together
Dim LastCol As Long
Dim LastRow As Long

' you never mentioned which sheet to copy from, I used the first index
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)
    LastCol = .Range("B3").End(xlToRight).Column
    LastRow = .Range("B3").End(xlDown).Row
    .Range("B3", .Cells(LastRow, LastCol)).Copy ' <-- Copy without Select
End With

' Paste without Select
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
            :=False, Transpose:=False
```

Comment: And, of course, get rid of the copy/paste with `wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").Resize(LastRow - 2, LastCol - 1).Value = .Range("B3").Resize(LastRow - 2, LastCol - 1).Value` ?  ;-)

Answer (score 3):

If you try exactly the steps in the code manually, you will find it also fails.  The issue is that inbetween copying the cells and trying to paste them, you are creating a new workbook and saving it.  This cancels copy/paste mode (i.e. the "marching ants" around the copied range disappear), so there is nothing to paste.

The solution is to not use `Selection` at all.  In general any time you find yourself writing `.Select` in VBA you're doing it wrong (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba-macros) for detail).  Here is how I would re-write your code:

```
Dim wk As Workbook

Set wk = Workbooks.Add
wk.SaveAs Filename:=ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "Budget.xlsx"

ThisWorkbook.Range("B3").CurrentRegion.Copy
wk.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("B3").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
```